# HttpClient .NET 4.6.1 Initial Request Delayed

Tags: .net, sockets, com, httpclient

I'm encountering odd behavior with the use of the HttpClient class within an EXCEL COM Addin.

**The initial attempt to call into the API takes 20-30 seconds.** After that the same request or any other request returns almost immediately. Below is the code that I'm running:

At the startup of the add-in (Called Once)

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://powertoolstest.mvwc.com/") };
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
```

The first use of the HttpClient:

```
 DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
 var result = await Client.GetAsync("api/Ping");
 result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 DateTime End = DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan TotalTime = End - Start;
```

- The first time this code is executed it can take anywhere from 20-30 seconds.
- All subsequent attempts run in under 1 second. Usually 300-500 milliseconds.
- **A wireshark trace didn't even pick up activity until the attempt had been running for almost all of the 30 seconds.  Once it did pick up the Request, the request itself took on 300-500 milliseconds.  This eliminates server configuration as a possible culprit.**

The delay appears to be in **System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind**.  Specifically I believe it is when it calls:

```
// This may throw ObjectDisposedException.
            SocketError errorCode = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.bind(
                m_Handle,
                socketAddress.m_Buffer,
                socketAddress.m_Size);
```

- Using .NET Framework 4.6.1
- We use HTTPClient in standalone Desktop Apps (.NET Core) and never had this issue.
- Built a console app using 4.6.1 and used same code, and also could not reproduce. Only happening withi EXCEL COM Add-in.

I tried turning Proxy search off, that didn't help.  Any suggestions on security settings or configuration that could be causing this delay?

The stack trace for the initial request:

```
 System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(System.Net.EndPoint endPointSnapshot, System.Net.SocketAddress socketAddress) Line 940          C#     Taking 20-30 seconds on HTTPClient
               System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(System.Net.EndPoint localEP) Line 934             C#
               System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, bool flowContext, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) Line 6899    C#
               System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) Line 2852    C#
               System.dll!System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(bool connectFailure, System.Net.Sockets.Socket s4, System.Net.Sockets.Socket s6, ref System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket, ref System.Net.IPAddress address, System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketState state, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, out System.Exception exception) Line 1449       C#
               System.dll!System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(System.Net.PooledStream PooledStream, object owner, bool async, out System.Net.IPAddress address, ref System.Net.Sockets.Socket abortSocket, ref System.Net.Sockets.Socket abortSocket6) Line 264            C#
               System.dll!System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(object owningObject, bool async, System.Net.GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) Line 157           C#
               System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(bool async, System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest) Line 1084        C#
               System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(bool onSubmitThread, System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Net.TriState needReConnect) Line 953       C#
               System.dll!System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, bool forcedsubmit) Line 752                C#
               System.dll!System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, string connName) Line 409                C#
               System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint servicePoint) Line 4188                C#
               System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) Line 2021       C#
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.RequestState state) Line 1089 C#
               System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartRequest(object obj) Line 946             C#
               System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SendAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 921     C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() Line 2884             C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Line 2498      C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) Line 2861              C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 980          C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 928                C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Line 2827            C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Line 2767             C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Line 2704       C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 820            C#
               mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Line 1161             C#
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a can of worms by using the Excel interop in this way. I HIGHLY recommend you switch to OpenXML...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: I recognize the advantages of moving to the Office Addin model vs the legacy VSTO or COM Addin approach. But this is not an answer to the question above.  And while the add-in is hosted within a Microsoft EXCEL Process, the code above makes no calls into the Excel Interop.

Comment: And yet the Excel COM add-in seems to be your only variance.  MS Office COM components are not intended for unattended use.  If you drill deeper I promise you will find an error underneath it all that is coming from there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Office Addin model.  OpenXML is the OpenDoc interface nuget for office documents...

Answer (score 0):

This delay in the HTTP request ended up being because of Trend Micro Firewall Service, which acts uniquely against Microsoft EXCEL.  The firewall did not block the request, but caused a significant delay in the DNS lookup.  This is why the behavior was only present in EXCEL and not in the stand alone desktop applications.  It is a legacy issue with an older version of Trend Micro which hasn't kept up with Office 365.